# Using an array value to retrieve from another array

Tags: php, arrays, database, multidimensional-array

I have created  an array, one of the  is intended to be a string used by php to display a field from a record retrieved from sqlite3.

My problem is that ... it doesn't.

The array is defined, "1" being the first database field, and "2" is the second database field:

**EDIT : I have re-defined the problem as a script so you can see the whole thing:**

```
//If I have an array (simulating a record retrieved from database):
$record = array(
    name => 'Joe',
    comments => 'Good Bloke',
    );

//then I define an array to reference it:
$fields = array( 
    1 => array(
    'db_index' => 'name',
    'db_type' => 'TEXT',
    'display' => '$record["name"]',
    'form_label' => 'Name',
    ),
    2 => array(
    'db_index' => 'comments',
    'db_type' => 'TEXT',
    'display' => '$record["comments"]',
    'form_label' => 'Comments',
    ),  
);  

//If I use the lines:
print "expected output:\n";
print " Name = " . $record["name"] ."\n";
print " Comments = " . $record["comments"] ."\n";

//I display the results from the $record array correctly.
//However if I try & use the fields array with something like:
Print "Output using Array values\n";
foreach($GLOBALS["fields"] as $field)
    {
        $label = $field['form_label'];
        $it = $field['display'];    
        $line = "\"$label = \" . $it .\"\n\"";
        print $line;
    }
```

Output:

```
Expected output:
 Name = Joe
 Comments = Good Bloke
Output using Array values:
 Name = $record["name"] 
 Comments = $record["comments"]
```

Comment: yes, "echo" can also be used instead of "print", but it does not change the output.

Comment: $record["name"] have some value or it will be printed as it is ?

Comment: Don't really understand what you're trying to ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call variable from string. Just concatenate it :

```
foreach($GLOBALS["fields"] as $field){
    $label = $field['form_label'];
    $it = $field['display'];

    eval("$it = ".$it);
    $line = $label." = ".$it."\n";
    print $line;
}
```

Well, how do it looks ?

Comment: Yes, a nicer way to construct the string, but it still produces the same result:Name = $record["name"]Comments = $record["comments"]

Comment: You have changed the way that the output string is constructed, but you have not addressed the main question.
Your solution still produces the same incorrect output 

Name = $record["name"]
Comments = $record["comments"]

Not the expected outputs.